# Is it possible to do load testing with Selenium with many instances of cloud-based virtual machines?

Tags: selenium, testing, cloud, load, load-testing

Suppose we have a simple Selenium script where the tool queries a website's search field and records the response time.

Would it be possible to have 100*n virtual machines replicate this same action simultaneously, and record their respective response times? Our end-goal is to determine at what user count the response time begins to slow significantly.

Comment: What base language are you using?  Python, Java, C#...

Comment: @Brian -- we would be using Python for this project

Comment: Okay.   I *strongly* recommend you don't use Selenium for load testing; it just isn't built for that.  You can do limited load testing with Selenium Grid, though.  It just isn't a widely-accepted practice.

Answer (score 0):

Up to certain extent you can perform load testing using Selenium via i.e. [Selenium Grid](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/) or your client programming language multi-threading features however it's not the best idea.

I would rather recommend converting your Selenium tests into load tests, for example if you set your Selenium tests to use i.e. Apache JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) [as the proxy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/) and run your tests JMeter will capture the HTTP requests made by the browser and create [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers out of it.

Most probably you will need to [perform the correlation of dynamic parameters](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) and [parameterization](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/data-parameterization-in-jmeter/) of the requests (i.e. each virtual user should have its own credentials, etc.) but on the other hand you will get [nice looking HTML report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and will be able to simulate your 100 users (in fact much more) from only one mid-range modern computer